# iTunes creating playlists on its own

Tags: itunes, playlists

Why does iTunes create a new playlist and start playing a few seconds from each one when I try to add albums to my library?
It means deleting about 400+ playlists, and having to wait a few hours for it to finish adding them all before I can actually listen to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded the album, often they come with a playlist file, which can be opened to play all the songs in order. I often personally use these with VLC when I'm on the go. Check the folder that has the files in it for a .pls file. When you add the files to iTunes, it may be opening the .pls file. Just look for it, and remove it. It is generally titled after the album.